# Linking two forms in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, forms, post

I have an HTML form that handles some basic information. When the button for completing the form is clicked, I have a popup asking for additional information that appears (this is a div that is hidden until button click event). What I want to know is if there is a way to link those two forms together so that a final submit will POST all data on both forms?

Ideas I've Considered:

1. On button click, pass the 11 fields from form one into 11 hidden fields from form 2.
2. On final submit, create my own post call via javascript.

Both of these would work, but seem sort of hacky to me. I'd rather have a true method of linking two form submits if there is one. Anyone?

Comment: If you need just one post, forget about 2 forms. Use just one main `form` area, and declare the `div` *inside* this main form. The form submit will include all fields that way.

Comment: @rsenna Is there no way to link the two seperate forms together? I've been using an absolutely positioned div defined in a master page as my popup by ajaxing in the information as-needed, that way I can reuse the forms on different pages where they are necessary.

Comment: It's also worth noting that in ASP.NET WebForms (which I assume you're using), you can have only one form with `runat="server"` per page. If there's a sound reason for having two *separate* forms, let us know what that reason is. If the reason is validation, use validation groups.

Comment: @Snixtor I'm actually just using regular HTML form submit with POST method, not asp.net webforms. I'm accessing the data with the Request object server-side.

Comment: If you're going to have two separate forms, then I don't think you have many options other than what you've already suggested. I still don't see a reason why you *need* two forms, or at least not two forms that are going to submit together. Ordinarily, in WebForms, the `Form` is on the master page anyway. If you want to move the entire div in and out of the form so you choose when it's included in the form based on some client-side logic, use appendTo - http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/appendTo

Comment: @Snixtor Having two seperatre forms fits with my already developed structure, but it looks like the best path is to alter that structure in this specific case. I'll go with the internal div method, as it seems more streamlined compared to my first two options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just make the first button a NON ASP.NET button (i.e. just a regular HTML button)... with an onclick event which shows the hidden div. The Submit button on the hidden div would be the ASP.NET button which submits the entire form (data from both parts) to your ASPX?

Comment: I am using non ASP.NET buttons. How do you get two seperate forms to submit with one button?